# Creating a generic type that "maps" over array

Tags: typescript

Given an array of functions

```
const arrayOfFunctions = [
    () => 1,
    () => 2,
    () => 3,
]
```

I can get the first return type like this:

```
type FirstReturnType = ReturnType<typeof x[0]>
```

I am trying to "map" over `typeof x` and return all of the types like this:

What is wrong with this type?

```
type ReturnTypeArray<M extends Array<Function>> = {
    [K in M]: ReturnType<M[K]>
}
```

Then with this I can get rid of duplicates and create one type.

```
export type UnionToIntersection<U> =
    (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never
```

Comment: Should it not be `ReturnType<typeof M[K]>`?

Comment: @TylerRoper I am not sure. The compiler is complaining about `K in M`.

Comment: Understood. Perhaps you could edit your question to provide that information - it may be useful debugging information for others. :)

Answer (score 1):

I was missing `keyof`.

```
type ReturnTypeArray<M extends Array<Function>> = {
    [K in keyof M]: M[K] extends ((...args: any[]) => any) ? ReturnType<M[K]> : never 
}
```